# How to create a blog community?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I work for a travel agency, they have a website, from here they want to give the option to their travels to create their own subdomain with a wordpress blog inside.

More or less what the webpage http://wordpress.com/ offers its users.

What do I need? And plz links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution might be to use "[Wordpress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/)", the "multi-user" version of wordpress ; install it on some webserver, and configure it ; and it should do what you want

Actually, like said on its website *(quoting)* :

> WordPress MU, or multi-user, is
>   designed to do exactly that. It is
>   most famously used for WordPress.com
>   where it serves tens of millions of
>   hits on millions of blogs each day.

So, this should be quite OK for your needs ;-)

For more informations, you can take a look at [its readme](http://trac.mu.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/README.txt), which describe how to install and configure and all that.